# Discover available clock types at compile time

Tags: c, gcc, clang

[Ubuntu 14.04, 3.16.0-34-generic Kernel, GCC 4.8.4, Clang 3.5.0]

I'm writing some elapsed time performance routines for an application I have, and I would like to do it in a cross-platform manner.
I would like to write it in such a way that the right clock type is selected during compile, rather than run-time (which I can do by testing for failures and using fallbacks).

The `clock_getres(2)` man page states:

`On POSIX systems on which these functions are available, the symbol _POSIX_TIMERS is defined in <unistd.h> to a value greater than 0.  The symbols _POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK,  _POSIX_CPUTIME,  _POSIX_THREAD_CPUTIME
       indicate that CLOCK_MONOTONIC, CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID are available.  (See also sysconf(3).)`

I have included in my code , , and  but my conditional compile statements don't recognise the symbol `_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK`.  It always prints the 'gettimeofday' message.  I've tried GCC and Clang but get the same result.
My code below is incomplete (and incorrect) and I would appreciate some assistance on how to do this right.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <features.h>
#include <stdio.h>    // printf (otherwise forward declaration warning)
#include <stdlib.h>   // NULL
#include <sys/time.h>

long long get_utime(void)
{
        struct timeval tv;
        if (gettimeofday(&tv, NULL) == -1) return -1LL;

        long long t = (long long) tv.tv_usec +
                        (long long) tv.tv_sec * 1000000LL;
        return t;
}


int main() {

  union time{
    struct timespec tSpec;
    long long tLL;
  } myT;

#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &myT.tSpec);
  printf("CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW\n");
#elif _POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &myT.tSpec);
  printf("CLOCK_MONOTONIC\n");
#else
  myT.tLL = get_utime();
  printf("gettimeofday\n");
#endif // CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW

  return 0;
}
```

I'm not using any configure or auto-configure software.

Also, a comment about the relative speeds of CLOCK_MONOTONIC & CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW would be nice.  I understand the difference and their limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren’t declaring the headers and feature-test macros that the `man` page says you need.  This works:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE     200809L  // <- This was missing.
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE       700      // <- This is optional.

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>    // printf (otherwise forward declaration warning)
#include <stdlib.h>   // NULL
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>     // <- This was missing.

long long get_utime(void)
{
        struct timeval tv;
        if (gettimeofday(&tv, NULL) == -1) return -1LL;

        long long t = (long long) tv.tv_usec +
                        (long long) tv.tv_sec * 1000000LL;
        return t;
}


int main() {

  union time{
    struct timespec tSpec;
    long long tLL;
  } myT;

#ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &myT.tSpec);
  printf("CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW\n");
#elif _POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &myT.tSpec);
  printf("CLOCK_MONOTONIC\n");
#else
  myT.tLL = get_utime();
  printf("gettimeofday\n");
#endif // CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: '@Lorehead: (cheers) are you able to comment on the relative speeds of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` & `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`?

Comment: Afraid not.  I haven’t ever used `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` because it’s less portable (the POSIX standard defines `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`).  I’m not sure I understand your question: the performance of the system calls themselves is not going to be significant, and whether the hardware clock runs fast or slow on average is going to be a peculiarity of your hardware.  But let’s say your box’s clock runs 1% too fast.  From the documentation, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` will consistently tell you you’re running faster than you are, while `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` will jump back a lot whenever `ntp` syncs.

Comment: What does defining `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` do?
I haven't seen that line in any `clock_gettime` man page.

Comment: @StefanFabian It’s a feature-test macro that enables all extensions defined in the 2008 version of the POSIX standard and disables a few deprecated functions. This is a function from POSIX rather than ISO C, so on some implementations, you might need the feature-test macro to use `clock_gettime()` at all. In any case, I’ve gotten in the habit of declaring the feature-test macros for the API I’m writing for in a header file that I include everywhere.